# How to build custom UITableViewController with Checkboxes and cell border highlight with space between cells like Apple COVID 19 App?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, uiswitch

I am trying create custom UITableViewController with below design... I am thinking of using UISwitch to implement checkbox but how can i implement custom space separated rounded corner shadow cells with blue border highlighting upon click?

[image: COVID-19]

The below code is what i have tried so far but it's not rendering the expected outcome

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dailyQuestions.count
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dailytrackercell", for: indexPath) as! DailyTrackerCell     
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true        
        cell.trackerQuestionLabel.text = dailyQuestions[indexPath.row]
        cell.trackerImage.image = UIImage(named: dailyTrackerImgs[indexPath.row])
        cell.contentView.setCardView()     
        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func switchAction(_ sender: Any) {        
        if(switchConnection.isOn){
            //Checkbox Turn ON
        }else{
            //Checkbox Turn OFF
        }        
    }    
}

extension UIView {

    func setCardView(){
        layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        layer.borderColor  =  UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 5.0
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowColor =  UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:5, height: 5)
        layer.masksToBounds = true
       // layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't throw one stone to catch two birds.

Comment: Ok can you please help how to tackle at least the uitableview card view with space separated cells?

Comment: for gap create a custom view inside tableview cell and for that view give top spacing and set border color and border width.